Jpql recursive query problem resolving entity name
I'm working with SpringBoot 3.2.5 and Hibernate 6.4.4 and I want to create a jpql recursive query. I have the following query
    @Query("""
        WITH modules AS (
            SELECT m1 module FROM ModuleJpa m1
            WHERE m1.product = :product and m1.parent is null
            UNION ALL
            SELECT m2 module FROM ModuleJpa m2
            JOIN modules mt ON m2.parent = mt.code
        )
        select m.module from modules m
        """)


based on the following article: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-with-recursive-query/
but I'm getting the following error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.EntityTypeException: Could not resolve entity name 'modules'

With https://in.relation.to/2023/02/20/hibernate-orm-62-ctes/ it seems to me that this is the way to do it.
Does anyone know what the problem could be?
I have this done with a native query, but I prefer to use a jpql query if possible.
PD: I'm not be able to add another library to do this like Blaze-Persistence.
Thanks in advance!
